# To adjust primefaces datatable size,live scrolling with screen size

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with live scrolling feature. The table fits fine in my development machine but the user of this app has larger screen.It would be good if the datatable fits according to the screen size. Also the height of the datatable should get adjusted with more number of rows for live scroll. Currently I have 15 rows for live scrolling. It would be good if the scroll rows increases with the height of the screen. Please help me in this regard.

My datatable code snippet:

```
 <h:form id="form">
   <div id="content">
      <h:selectOneMenu id="workspaceOptions" />
      <f:selectItem id="option1" itemLabel="Assignments"
         itemValue="assignment" />

      </h:selectOneMenu>


      <p:dataTable id="workSpaceList" var="data"
         value="#{workSpaceBean.lazylpId}" widgetVar="multiSelection"
         selection="#{workSpaceBean.selectedRows}" resizableColumns="true"
         liveScroll="true" scrollRows="15" scrollWidth="85%"
         scrollHeight="69%" styleClass=".ui-datatable-hor-scroll"
         tableStyle="table-layout:auto;width:100%;" scrollable="true"
         filteredValue="#{workSpaceBean.filteredWorkSpaceItems}">

         <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{workSpaceBean.onRowSelect}"
            update=":editWrkSp:display" oncomplete="multiDialog.show()" />

         <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:5%" />
            .
            .
            .
            <p:column headerText="Insured" filterBy="#{data.insuredName}"
            sortBy="#{data.insuredName}" style="width:20%">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.insuredName}" />
            <!--   style="width:250px" -->
         </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="City" filterBy="#{data.custAddress_City}"
            sortBy="#{data.custAddress_City}">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.custAddress_City}" />
         </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
   </div>
   </form>
```

CSS of the entire page

```
    body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: #E8F0F8;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #194775;
    position: fixed;
}

#sidepanel {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D9E6F3;
    margin-top: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: #4A7EBB;

    /* z-index:1; */
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    /* padding-right: 10px;
   padding-bottom:90px; */
    right: 30px;
    top: -25px;
    /* bottom:10px; */
}

.title1 {
    font-family: Agency FB;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #7F7F7F;
    font-style: bold;
    /* float: right; */
    text-align: left;
    /* padding-right: 10px; */
    font-weight: bold;
    /* padding-bottom:20px; */
}

.accordionMenu .ui-accordion-header a {
    background: #194775;
    color: white;
}

.accordionMenu .ui-accordion-content {
    /* color:#254061!important */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #B9CDE5;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 90px 0 0 180px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E8F0F8;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #194775;
    width: 170px;
    /* text-align:left; */
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.selectMenu {
    /* float:right; */
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.ui-datatable-hor-scroll .ui-datatable-tablewrapper,.scrolling-div .ui-datatable-tablewrapper
    {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% padding-bottom:    5px;
}

.datatable {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.calendarStyle {
    width: 250px;
}

.ui-corner-top {
    display: none;
}

.ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default {
    /* vertical-align:middle; */
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you get us your generetad HTML instead of the one you provided? I'm only asking this because i sense this can also be fixed using css overflow property, and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with function HTML will need to be built in order to confirm that.

Comment: If you used % instead of pixels in the css portion, wouldn't that adjust the document relative to the screen size?

Comment: If yoU want to do that, you can try with JavaScript. I think this is what you want: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

Comment: Check the documentation. scrollHeight="69%" is not correct. This attribute receive only Integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In at least PrimeFaces 5.1, you **can** define the scrollHeight (and width) as a percentage of the container.

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Scrolling has 3 modes; x, y and x-y scrolling that are defined by 
>   scrollHeight
>     and 
>   scrollWidth.
>   These two scroll attributes can be defined using integer values indicating fixed pixels or **percentages** relative to the container dimensions.

See also (5.3 docs and source):

- http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#165
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L612